# COM object lifetime management in an ATL service

Tags: c++, com, windows-services, atl

I'm trying to get my head around the concept of writing a Windows Service using ATL.

I've created a project and understand that I can override CAtlServiceModuleT functions to achieve my needs for the service.

What I'd like to do is have the service create a COM object (called Manager) that deals with the scheduling and execution of jobs.

How can I create a single instance of my COM object that's available throughout the lifetime of the service that deals with all jobs?

I envisage writing a client program that calls functions on interfaces exposed by Manager, to Create/Read/Update/Delete jobs.

My thinking is that the Service won't create the Manager object until my client program connects to it - and when the last client disconnects from it, COM would destroy the manager - thereby killing it's ability to process jobs.

Any good documentation on this would be appreciated!

Update:

Would it be as simple as calling CoCreateInstance from say an overridden version of CAtlServiceModuleT::Run(), then when the service is shutdown, making a final Release call?!

Comment: This article may help, although things may have gotten easier since then: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/activex/activex0197.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CComClassFactorySingleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7b5axx6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to create such an object.